# ISAKMP problem on F5 BIG-IP

Tags: ipsec, f5

I'm trying to move a site-to-site IPsec tunnel from a Cisco ASA 5505 and a BIG-IP LTM+AFM version 12.1.0. The tunnel was up and traffic flowed properly when the tunnel was terminated on ASA but not any longer. I have configured IKE phase 1 and IPsec phase 2 and traffic selectors with same parameters that were configured on the ASA and I have also configured a forwardning virtual server but my BIG-IP seems to drop ISAKMP traffic, it answers back to the peer with ICMP port 500 unreachable. What can be wrong? Am I missing something in Network Firewall? I have added ESP and ISAKMP to the Global rule and I can see Count increasing. But phase 1 doesn't work anyway.

I have followed https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip-tmos-tunnels-ipsec-12-1-0/10.html

Best regards, 
Andreas

Comment: "_it answers back to the peer with ICMP port 500 unreachable._" Please include the exact messages. This doesn't make any sense because ICMP doesn't use ports (layer-4 addresses) the way TCP and UDP do.

Comment: An example (the F5 is `1.1.1.1`, the Cisco ASA is `2.2.2.2`):

07:00:30.781207 IP 2.2.2.2.isakmp > 1.1.1.1.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 I ident in slot1/tmm0 lis=


07:00:30.781263 IP 1.1.1.1 > 2.2.2.2: ICMP 1.1.1.1 udp port isakmp unreachable, length 36 out slot1/tmm0 lis=

Comment: Problem solved by changing mode in the IPsec profile first to IPsec interface and then back to Tunnel again... After this "change" the tunnel got up and I was able to reach the private network on the other side of the tunnel.

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing mode in the IPsec profile first to IPsec interface and then back to Tunnel again... After this "change" the tunnel got up and I was able to reach the private network on the other side of the tunnel.